# How can I go back to the previous version of QGIS on Linux Mint?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, linux, update, linux-mint

After the last update of #QGIS yesterday July 21, on Linux Mint, it does not run the program. How can I go back to the previous version?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by removing the `symbology-style.db` from your profile.

```
rm ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/symbology-style.db
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44293) for more details. Apparently, this bug can also affect windows machines.